# Literature Review Confusion

Tags: literature-review

I'm very new to the research domain and I'm extremely confused, let me explain further. For the literature review I've done assume that I have 1 topic, that comprises of three research papers say A,B,C. Now I put these papers in chronological order, I then take paper A and summarize it. What I mean here is that I discuss what the papers purpose was, how the authors met the papers purpose and mention the results. After this I then explain what is learned from each paper and what I can take forward in the proposed research and Introduce the next paper, in this case paper B. I do the same process for paper B etc. My question is that I've been told that this approach is wrong and that a literature review is like "telling a story" but frankly I can't see where I'm going wrong?? Can someone please help explain where exactly I am going wrong?